# Draw UIView in CGContext

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, cgcontext

I am trying to draw simple `UIView` in `CGContext`.
I am drawing a string properly, but the `UIView` is not being drawn.

Method used for drawing the view:

```
view.draw(view.layer, in: context)
```

But it does not work. Is there any other way to draw a `UIView` in `CGContext`?

```
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics

let contextSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 400)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(contextSize, false, 0.0)

guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
    fatalError("no context")
}

let size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 20)
let point = CGPoint(x: 20, y: 240)
let rect = CGRect(origin: point, size: size)

let text = "TEST"
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 6).lineHeight
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] =  [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12),
                                                   .foregroundColor: UIColor.cyan,
                                                   .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle]
text.draw(with: rect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: nil)


let view = UIView()
view.backgroundColor = .magenta
view.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
view.frame = CGRect(origin: point, size: size)

view.draw(view.layer, in: context)

let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is

```
view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
```

This will draw to whatever your current context is being set to. And that should already be your context since you do `context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`. I tried it with your code and it seems to work. I got an image with rectangle with borders and some text.

Comment: Perfect! I would use view.frame, though. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @izik461 Yes, any frame should do. It depends on what you are looking for. Using bounds will draw it at the top left.

Comment: Many thanks for that. Saved my evening.